# Parallelism in stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

I have a stored procedure to insert few records on daily basis. Same logic gets executed for each day but in a sequential manner. So to improve the performance, I was thinking to introduce parallelism. So is there a way or could some one point me to some example where I can run some logic in a stored procedure in parallel.

EDIT:
The query I am using in my stored procedure is :

```
INSERT INTO tmp (time_interval, cnt, dat, txn_id) SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.timeslice, '%H:%i') as time_interval
     , COUNT(m.id) as cnt
     , date(d.timeslice) as dat
     , "test" as txn_id
  FROM ( SELECT min_date + INTERVAL n*60 MINUTE AS timeslice
           FROM ( SELECT DATE('2015-05-04') AS min_date
                       , DATE('2015-05-05') AS max_date) AS m
         CROSS
           JOIN numbers
          WHERE min_date + INTERVAL n*60 MINUTE < max_date
       ) AS d
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN mytable AS m
    ON m.timestamp BETWEEN d.timeslice
                        AND d.timeslice + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
GROUP
    BY d.timeslice;
```

This query groups the records on hour basis for each day and inserts in tmp table. So I want to run this query in parallel for each day instead of sequential.

Thanks.

Comment: can you set example ?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `d` a set of DATETIMEs that represent the 24 hours of one day?  My gut says it can be simplified a bunch.  It can be sped up by adding `WHERE n BETWEEN 0 AND 23`.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT '2015-05-04' + INTERVAL n*60 MINUTE AS timeslice
    FROM numbers
    WHERE n BETWEEN 0 AND 23
```

What is in `mytable`?  In particular, is the 'old' data static or changing?  If it is unchanging, why repeatedly recompute it?  Compute only for the last hour, store it into a permanent (not tmp) table.  No need for parallelism.

If the data is changing, it would be better to avoid

```
ON m.timestamp BETWEEN d.timeslice
                   AND d.timeslice + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
```

because (I think) it will not optimize well.  Let's see the `EXPLAIN SELECT...`.

In that case, use a stored procedure to compute the start and end times and construct (think `CONCAT`) the ON clause with constants in it.

Back to your question...
There is no way in MySQL, by itself, to get parallelism.  You *could* write separate scripts to do the parallelism, each with its own parameters and connection.

Comment: Your suggestion is very good, but just not getting how to replace " d.timeslice + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE" part.

Comment: Make the other changes I suggested, then we can readdress that suggestion.  Meanwhile, add a description of the goal to the question; I am having trouble deducing the intent.

Comment: I changed the whole query, and it is working as expected now. thanks for the suggestion to work on the query.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear.  :)